# Expect Stuck in Infinite Loop

Tags: loops, expect

I can only seem to get expect commands to work in an expect statement eg, expect {}. So the code below will exectute but the loop continues to see the default prompt which is "# ".

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set filename [lindex $argv 0]
set timeout -1
spawn ssh user@IP
set pass "pass"
expect {
        password: {send "$pass\r" ; exp_continue}
    "# " {send "show card table all\r" ; exp_continue}
 }
```

The above code continutes to run the command over and over. I cant seem to be able to isolate expect/send commands.

I can not simply enter:

```
expect "# "
send "command"
```

Nothing will execute outside of expect {}

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many times are you supposed to `send "show card table all\r"`? The way you've written it, every time you see `#`, you'll send that command.

Assuming you only need to see it once, remove `exp_continue` from that action:

```
expect {
    password: {send "$pass\r" ; exp_continue}
    "# " {send "show card table all\r"}
}
expect "# " 
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

That will send the password as many times as the password prompt appears. Then, if a "prompt" is seen, the "show card" command is sent and that expect command ends. I then expect a prompt, send "exit" (if that's the right command) and wait until the spawned process ends.

Comment: Hey, BINGO. I thought I had tried that before and it failed. Perfect thanks.